# My google calendar doesnt show on Macbook while is being shown on ios

Tags: macos, ios, google-sync

This is what I see on iphone:

[image]

[image]

but on macbook I do not see my gmail events. Why?

[image]

How to turn it on on both: osx and ios?

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't activated the calendar service for Gmail.

On your Mac go to settings->accounts
If your Gmail account is present then do step 1. 
If not do step 2

1. Click on the account-> tick the box next to calendar
2. Click the plus button -> select Gmail-> login -> make sure calendar is activated for that account